How can I use the same APK across Internal, Closed, and Production environments with different API endpoints?
An Android app needs to be published to the Play Store with the following configurations:

Internal Testing: The app should use the development (dev) endpoint for internal testing purposes. This allows the development team to test new features and fixes in a controlled environment before releasing them to a wider audience.

Closed Testing: The app should use the System Integration Testing (SIT) endpoint for closed testing. This phase involves a select group of testers who can evaluate the app's integration with other systems and ensure that it functions correctly in a pre-production environment.

Production: The app should use the actual production endpoint when it is ready for the general public. This ensures that all users interact with the live production servers, providing the intended user experience and functionality.


Can some one explain how to use the same APK with different Endpoints based on the APK envornment?

You can make use of Firebase Config flag and based on that flag received in app change the Base URL

or setup gradle file with debug and release section based on build generation and option selection your BASE URL will alter

I don't think it's feasible since APK doesn't recognize which testing lane/environment they currently belong to.
